# Dependency Management issue in Intellij idea 12.0.4

Tags: intellij-idea, dependency-management

I am facing a problem modifying dependencies within Intellij12.04.

Under my project folder, I have two modules, the second of which depends on the first:

- *a.b.c.somebusiness*
  ---> *a.b.c.tests*

I want to remove one dependency from a.b.c.tests and add it into a.b.c.somebusiness module, but I don't want to create a circular dependency tree. When I try to remove the dependency from the a.b.c.tests module and add it into the a.b.c.somebusiness module, I am getting the following error:

*"Source root "C:\Perforce\depot\Projest\Main\a.b.c.tests\src\test" cannot be defined in module "Main" because it belongs to content of nested module "a.b.c.tests""*

I don't know what to do to resolve this issue. Can anyone suggest an approach that would fix the error I'm receiving?

Comment: What exactly are you doing on this step: *i am trying to remove the dependency from a.b.c.tests module*?

Comment: in the a.b.c.tests module, i have added dependency on a local directory i.e. C:\SomeDir\config. This directory has a properties file which has details about VM e.g its IP, port, username, password. I want to use the same directory dependency in a.b.c.somebusiness. But i am not able to do it. When i try to add this directory dependency in a.b.c.somebusiness, on applying the dependency from Module dependencies, i get the above error.

Comment: Remove this directory dependency from a.b.c.tests, add it to a.b.c.somebusiness instead, enable Export checkbox, this way both modules will have this dependency in the classpath as a.b.c.tests depends on a.b.c.somebusiness.

Comment: yeah, i tried this way.. i didn't apply the changes till i have added the dependency into a.b.c.somebusiness and enabled the export checkbox. When i was done, i clicked apply button. Still, i got the same error.

Comment: Can you provide an isolated test case project to reproduce this problem?

Comment: For now, i found a temp solution. I copied the directory dependency from iml file of a.b.c.tests to iml file of a.b.c.somebusiness. I can do it and run the code without failure. I am not sure, why i can't do it through module dependencies explorer.

Comment: You can try to remove the dependency, apply changes, add it to another module, apply again.

Comment: yeah, i tried it on another module in the same project. It results into similar error.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at using apache `maven` and the project object model (`pom.xml` file)

When you define your dependencies under `<dependencies>` in the pom.xml, they are managed automatically by IntelliJ. So you will never have such problems from moving dependencies into file folders manually.

If you configure it similar to the fashion shown below, your dependencies will work automagically.

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>a.b.c</groupId>
            <artifactId>a-b-c-tests</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>some.other.org</groupId>
            <artifactId>some.other.dep</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

How to get started: install apache maven and add a pom.xml at the root of your project. Right click it to add in as a maven file in IntelliJ.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The best approach to isolate issue faced is to use `Apache Maven`. It gives following advantages and will be easy for you to manage dependencies in a cleaner and efficient way. Hope this will help a new comer.

- The task of downloading Jar files and other dependencies is done automatically.
- In Maven, it’s easy to add new dependencies by writing the dependency code in the `pom.xml` file.
- Makes it easy for the developer to build a project in different environments without worrying about the dependencies, processes, etc.

Having said that, please follow these steps to **fix the issue**.

1. Go to InteliJ IDEA
2. Right click the Project and Click Add Framework Support and check
   the "Maven" option This will create pom.xml file for the project
3. Double click the pom.xml file and include dependencies as needed.
   (The dependencies could be found by searching via
   https://mvnrepository.com/)
4. When the dependencies are added it will automatically download, if
   does not, right click the project and select "Maven" and click
   "Reimport".
5. Now you are project is added with the dependencies you have
   specified.

Once above is completed, try to build the project in order to **deploy/run**.

1. Go to Run -> Edit Configuration -> Add New Configuration -> Select
   Maven -> Fill the name etc. -> Type 'clean install' in the 'Command
   Line' field and press OK.
2. Now you can run the Maven in the Run/Debug Configurations
3. The output can be seen in the target folder of your project
   directory.

Check this out for more information - Official Page for `Apache Maven`:

https://maven.apache.org/index.html